# windows callback function freezes with any new callback event

Tags: windows, callback

I wrote a Win32  backup program, that runs fine - however it will hang as soon as any callback event acours.

The function calls in case of IDC_F_BACKUP and IDC_F_SAVEAS work ok, but whenever the input and output folders
are defined and 'start' (IDC START) is hit, any other callback event (for example a mouse click or a window move)
will freeze this application (and it's icon changes to a windoews default one).

As I understood, a callback function should return within a short timeframe. I have no idea how to realize this
requirement since whenever the 'start' button has been hit the backup runs for much more than 30 minutes.

Here my windows procedure

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
 /* ========================================================================
 **                 Callback loop for the Windows procedure
 ** ========================================================================
 */
 {
   switch(msg) {
     //case WM_MOVE:
     //case WM_SHOWWINDOW:
     //case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING:
     case WM_PAINT:
     case WM_CREATE:
       DisplaySettings();
       ActivityMonitor(L"\0");
       break;
     case WM_CLOSE:
       DestroyWindow(hWnd);
       DestroyWindow(hWnd);
     case WM_DESTROY:
       PostQuitMessage(0);
       break;
     case WM_COMMAND: {
       switch(LOWORD(wParam)) {
         case IDC_START: {
           DWORD p;
           const WCHAR szEndMsg[]=L"====> backup successfully completed <====";

           if((szInpPath[0]==L'?') || (szOutpPath[0]==L'?')) {
             MessageBoxW( NULL, L"Path not found", L"Error",MB_OK );
           }else {
             // create and initialize error log file:
             strCopyW(&szOutpPath[nOP_End], (WCHAR*)L"\\skipped_files.log", MAX_PATH);
             //MessageBoxW( NULL, szOutpPath, L"Log file", MB_OK );
             hLog = _wfopen(szOutpPath, L"a+");
             Test((hLog!=0), L"can not create log file");
             szOutpPath[nOP_End] = L'\0';
             fwprintf(hLog, L"\n\n\n");
             for(p=0; p<20; p++) fwprintf(hLog, L"----");
             fwprintf(hLog, L"\nBackup starting at %s", szInpPath);
             fwprintf(hLog, L"\nFollowing files could not be archived:\n");
             // go ...
             BackupDirectory();  // <========== this function runs those 30 minutes ....
             ActivityMonitor(L" ");
             ActivityMonitor(szEndMsg);
             fwprintf(hLog, szEndMsg);
             InvalidateRect( hWnd, &rcMonitor, TRUE );   // invalidate the monitor area
             UpdateWindow(hWnd);
             //RedrawWindow(hWnd, &rcMonitor, 0, RDW_UPDATENOW);
             fclose(hLog);
             DisplaySettings();
             szInpPath[nIP_End] = L'\0';     // restore input path
             szOutpPath[nOP_End] = L'\0';    // restore output path
           }
           break;
         }
         case IDC_F_BACKUP:
           nIP_End = SelectPath(hWnd, szInpPath, L"Select the folder to be backed up");
           DisplaySettings();
           break;
         case IDC_F_SAVEAS:
           nOP_End = SelectPath(hWnd, szOutpPath, L"Create a folder for this backup");
           DisplaySettings();
           break;
         case IDC_VERSION:
           MessageBoxW( NULL, L"\n   FolderClone.exe     Version 1.1 /MN"
                              L"\n   Create a zip-backup of the selected"
                              L"\n   directory (archive all files per folder,"
                              L"\n   directory structure left unchanged).", L"  ?  ",MB_OK );
           break;
         case IDC_F_EXIT:
           PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
           break;
       }//switch(LOWORD(wParam))
       break;
       default:
         return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
     }//WM_COMMAND
     return 0L;
   }//switch(msg)
   return (0L);
 }
```

Comment: You probably need to create a new thread and do the long-running work in the thread.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. While I googled for this problem I got the impression that my code just takes too much time - but I was not sure that this was the real reason for this symtomes. But  I have no idea at all how to implement an independent second thread. I never worked with multi threading, how can I start this new thread from my IDC_START code? Can you provide  or pinpoint to an example (preferred in c, not cpp)?

Comment: Try this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-threads

Comment: Thank you - my problem is solved. Everything works fine - it was much easier than I had expected.